# Trusted Signon in IBM Cognos with SAML Token & JCE Policy

Tags: java, security, cognos, jce

I am trying to create a Custom Java Authentication Provider (CJAP) which is trying to read the SAML tokens (Version 1.1) passed from the source application (Trusted) to Cognos Application (Version 10.2.1 FP 1) (Application Server : Tomcat).

Also since the SAML tokens are passed in encrypted format we need to decrypt it using the JCE Policy

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

These policies needs to be placed in the in /bin64/jre/lib/security , However when I put these policy in the mentioned location the cognos service does not starts and when the cognos policy is present it does not decrypts the token and gives the error of invalid token,

Is there any way, where we can integrate cognos policy & jce policy which we are using or perhaps is there any way in which we can integrate SAML with Cognos.?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, I never did anything similar (

Have you tried debugging as in 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/0a7c97bb-6cf9-4ddb-a918-80994e7b444d/entry/how_to_debug_a_cognos_custom_security_provider_using_eclipse10?lang=en ? There are a few more debugging links in comments as well.

Comment: Thanks...for the information, as i got something new to explore, i didn't knew that we can debug our custom provider in ibm cognos.